# bind_result mysqli not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I made a website in localhost with xampp.
Now I put it in a server and nothing is working anymore.

Localhost:

```
$on124 = $mysqli_link->prepare("select * from online where ip=? order by id desc LIMIT 1");
$on124->bind_param('s', $ip);
$on124->execute();
$result_on124 = $on124->get_result();
$sb4154 = $result_on124->num_rows;
$on124->close();
```

get_result is not working, so I read that I need to change to bind_result:

```
$on124 = $mysqli_link->prepare("select id, ip, hora from online where ip = ? order by id desc LIMIT 1");
$on124->bind_param('s', $ip);
$on124->execute();
$result_on124 = $on124->bind_result($id, $ip, $hora);
$sb4154 = $result_on124->num_rows;
$on124->close();
```

but it gives me this:

> error: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]:
>   Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purposes of what you are trying to do, `get_result()` is unnecessary. You don't need to create a new variable to contain the `bind_result()`.

Instead of this,

```
$result_on124 = $on124->bind_result($id, $ip, $hora);
```

Try this

```
 $on124->bind_result($id, $ip, $hora);
```

Your new variables `$id, $ip, $hora` are now ready to use.

also, to be able to get `num_rows` from a prepared statement, you will need to store the result, like so

```
$on124->store_result();
```

before you call the `num_rows`

you can also free these afterward using

```
$on124->free_result();
```

--Edit for clarification--
Here's the full thing

```
$on124 = $mysqli_link->prepare("select id, ip, hora from online where ip = ? order by id desc LIMIT 1");
$on124->bind_param('s', $ip);
$on124->execute();
$on124->bind_result($id, $ip, $hora);
$on124->store_result();
$sb4154 = $on124->num_rows;
$on124->fetch();
$on124->free_result();
$on124->close();
```

Comment: note, I edited it to provide the full thing for clarification

Comment: it is perfect, thank you! can I use select * from...? bind_result need to have variables or can be blank? (like: bind_result(); ) thank you again

Comment: In bind_result, you must name the specific variables in your query.  You can actually name them anything you want (they don't have to match the table keys).  They are identified in the order they appear, much like bind_param.  And then you get them by using fetch() (note, I modified the answer above to include this;  I forgot it before).    Naming keys in your query is actually good practice; while `select *` may not matter for small tables, then can really bog down a system, so it's good to get into this habit

Comment: oh, ok! thank you very much, you help me a lot!!!! nice to have people like you here!